# Sorting ArrayList of Objects formed by Merging Query output List of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist

I want to sort an `ArrayList` by month of Date which is formed by merging 2 list got from Hibernate query output , but the problem is that the final `ArrayList` cannot be cast to any specific User Defined Class of my project.

```
sql = "select round(sum(d.displayCost),2), month(d.date) as  date, '0' as flag from Countinfo d where  year(d.date)=2015 and d.resultId is not null group by month(d.date) ";
query = session.createQuery(sql);

List list1 = query.list();

sql = " select round(sum(c.clickCost),2), month(c.date) as date, '1'  as flag from Countinfo c where  year(c.date)=2015 and c.resultId is not null group by month(c.date) order by date, flag";
query = session.createQuery(sql);

List resultSet = query.list();

resultSet.addAll(list1);

ListIterator iterator = resultSet.listIterator();
```

I want the `ResultSet` arraylist to be get sorted by month .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use `Collections.sort()` and pass in a appropriate `Comparator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this :

```
    Arrays.sort(resultSet.toArray(), new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) { 
            // cast your objects to the correct type (watch out for ClassCastException!), 
            // then compare their month fields
            // and return -1, 0 or 1 according to the contract of Comparator
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But thats the problem , to which class the object need to cast??,

Comment: you are selecting rows from a table named `Countinfo`, so I think you should create a DTO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that models the outcome of those queries. You could even use `Tuple` if you don't want to have a domain object for that, but you can use Tuple only with `Criteria Queries` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Thanks Francesco , it helped me to solve my  problem

Answer (score 0):

It's true you can sort the arrays by using the `Array.sort` but in your case why you want to iterate again rather you can get both the result already sorted by using `ORDER BY` in sql and then while adding (merging) the one list elements to other you can add one element at time by using the custom function which sort and inserts element at particular place.
Example code,

```
public void sortAndInsert(List resultSet, Object objToInsert)//Object is your own type
{      
  for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++) 
  {
    // if the element property is smaller we move to next element
    if (resultSet(i).MonthName < objToInsert.MonthName) //Maonth Name is just property name what I have used to compare on
        continue;
    else
    {  
       resultSet.add(i, x);
       return;
    }
  }    
}
```